# Display at most one infobox (google maps v3) at a time

Tags: google-maps

There are many issues opend for the google maps v3 infobox.js, but almost all of them are without answeres or with few answeres that are not working in everybody cases.

I personally opend all the suggested questions and none of them was helpfull for me.

1. Question 1

I am using infobox insted of default infowindow and i want when one infobox is opend (when i mouseover a marker) all the others should disapear. Also when i mouseout of the marker that infobox should disapear to. So its an application with lots of markers and when i mouse over one a infobox should apear and when i mouseover other marker, the previous infobox should disapear and the new one apears that corespund to the last marker.

Its obvious that i would like something very optimized since i will have more than 1000 markers on the map. (i guess a single infobox that will just change its content and its location)

1. Quesiton 2

I want when the infobox apeares, all the markers on the map to be under it, and just that marker that i am mouseover it to be upon  the infobox. I tryed with set Zindex and all that i could but nothing. I also change the mapPane and floatPane, but its or under all of them or uppon all of them, but in any case its uppon others and under the current marker.

I will apreacite very much if somebody will come with an answere. Thx (i stay near)

Comment: One question per question, please. Also, your rambling about infobox is out of place, just ask the questions.

Comment: Please read the FAQ of use of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see just one infobox, declare it as global variable

**PSEUDOCODE**

```
var globalib;

function setIb (){
   if (globalib && typeof globalib is INFOBOX) {
      globalib.close();
   }
   globalib = new Infobox...
...
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, this worked. So one problem at question 2 is fixed. I used : google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
   ib.close();
    }); to close the infobox when i mouseout of the marker but the problem is that even if i go with the mouse on the infobox it still disapear and it shouldn't.

Comment: I accepted it and i created another question visible here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211424/google-map-infobox-under-current-marker-and-on-top-of-others